# The right way to model multiple FACTs schema

Tags: database-design, dimensional-modeling, facttable, star-schema, slowly-changing-dimension

**Background**

I'm in a process of designing a database (using a STAR schema).

There are three tables to model: *products*, *tests*, *states*.

The database will be used to store results of *tests* conducted on *products* (in a great simplification). There can be many *tests* pointing out to a single product but each *test* is unique (they are not shared among *products*). Besides, I need to record the current *state* of the product, at the time when the *test* was conducted. Let's assume that the *state* of a *product* describes its current location and owner, which are changing very often. That will most likely involve SCD lvl 2 - to track the history of *state* changes and to be able to locate a *product* with all its *tests* as well as the *states* it had during these *tests*.

**Problem**

I'm not entirely sure how to model this problem. It seems obvious to store every *test* in a FACT table. This table would then consist of thousands of transactions. On the other hand, there will also be hundreds (and later thousands) of *products*, so I should probably keep them in a second FACT table. Then, there will also be thousands of *state* changes, so in order to record their entire history, I would need to keep them in a ... FACT table as well? I've been told that FACT tables are typically used to store multiple-rows data but on the other hand where are the DIMs in this model?

I also don't know how to model the relationships between these tables. *Products* - *states* is a 1:* relationship. *Products* - *tests* is a 1:* as well. Finally, *states* - *tests* is a 1:* too. I would then go with linking *products* to *states* and then *states* to *tests* (*products* 1<-* *states* 1<-* *tests*), what would allow me to find all *states* for a particular *product* and all *tests* (in all *states* or in a selected *state*). What do you think about that? The problem here is that, as I keep adding *states*, I have two options: either keep duplicating *products* in the *products* table (with added "recorded_timestamp" column) or use a SCD lvl 2 in *states* table, pointing out to the *products* table with a FK, but this would effectively make the *product* table a DIM!

Any help here would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, neither "star" nor "fact" are abbreviations, as isn't "dimension", so they should not be in all caps. "Fact tables" are called such because they contain facts. A "star schema" resembles (to some people) a star when represented graphically, in case there are many dimensions describing a single fact.

A *product* cannot be a fact, so it is a dimension. A *state* may or may not be a fact, so you should look harder at this entity to determine what it really is. A *test* is certainly a fact.

Depending on what you decide a *state* to be, your model would be either a two-point "star", with *product* and *state* as dimensions, or a one-legged snowflake. You could also find that the combination of *state* and *test* is indeed a fact, then you'll end up with a one-point "star".

Comment: I very much like how you cleared this out: "A product cannot be a fact, so it is a dimension. A state may or may not be a fact, so you should look harder at this entity to determine what it really is. A test is certainly a fact.".

Answer (score 1):

So the first question is: Are you absolutely sure you need to use a star schema?  Having worked in a number of warehouses built to varying levels of quality, I have found star schema to be: 1. Inflexible 2. Difficult to use (tons of joins) 3. Really bad for time series.

The way you have described things (Product, Product State, Test) along with the need to track points in time would generate something like this (slight embellishment for party/test):

[image]

If you need to get the state as of a certain test this is attainable by a simple join, which can be encapsulated in a view so users don't have to worry about getting the logic correct:

```
SELECT
  ProductTest.ProductId
 ,ProductTest.TestDtm
 ,ProductTest.TestCd
 ,<Other relevant columns>
 ,ProductState.OwnerId
 ,ProductState.<Location info> --Don't know if this is address or lat/long, use whatever works best for you
FROM
  ProductTest ProductTest
LEFT JOIN
  ProductState ProductState
    ON ProductState.ProductId = ProductTest.ProductId
         AND ProductState.UpdateDtm =
               (
                 SELECT
                   MAX(UpdateDtm)
                 FROM
                   ProductState
                 WHERE
                   ProductId = ProductTest.ProductId
                     AND UpdateDtm <= ProductTest.TestDtm
               )
```

Comment: For this to work well you will need to be use a database engine that allows/maintains clustered indexes/index organized tables.  That limits you (according to my limited memory) to SQL Server, MySQL (recent versions with InnoDb), Oracle, Sybase, and DB2.  Which really limits you to SQL Server and MySQL unless you (or the person paying) have very, very deep pockets.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer. I understand the limitations of the star schema. The solution you proposed would indeed work for this problem. However, to keep the question simple, I didn't mention other dimensions and relations involved, which are definitely easier to solve with a star schema - that's why I will stick with it. Nevertheless, thanks for help (due to low reputation, I can't upvote your answer sadly).

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone ends up having a similar problem to mine - here is how I solved it.

Firstly, following the suggestions found in other answers, I keep my *products* in a dim table and my *tests* (results of tests) in a fact. The problem now is how to store the *state* (history of state changes of a product).

Let's assume a state of a product is defined by attributes A, B and C, which are changing in time. We want to record the history of changes and relate the test results to any particular state in time.

I used mini-dimensions for that. Three mini-dim tables (for A, B and C) are all connected to the main fact table (*tests*). In this way we always know to which state a particular test relates.

In order to keep track of the history of state changes, I also connect these mini-dims to a factless fact table (which also has attributes such as *effective*, *expired*, *current* ).

This seems to solve both problems. Will now try to build it and update this answer if it doesn't really do the job.